# How to select an ntext column as binary/hex

Tags: sql, t-sql, unicode

I'm trying to debug a unicode issue in my application layer. To do this I would like to be able to quickly see the contents of an MS SQL column (ntext) in binary format (UTF-8 or UTF-16 in hex), so that I can identify the precise unicode characters involved.

To this end I would like to write a query to the effect of:

`SELECT CONVERT_TO_UTF16_HEX( [mytext] ) FROM [mytable] WHERE [id] = 123;`

How can I go about doing this?

(Edit: changed preference to UTF16).

Comment: Binary has no concept of utf 8 or 16. It is just bytes

Comment: Binary has to have a concept of UTF8 or UTF16, no? When unicode characters are serialized an encoding must be chosen.

Comment: In C# probably. In SQL Server, don't think so. There is only N-var-char for 2 bytes of storage, or non-N for 1 byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert twice, first to NVARCHAR(MAX), then to VARBINARY(MAX)

Sample

```
declare @mytable table (id int, mytext ntext)
insert @mytable select 123, 'someUNICODEütext'

SELECT convert(varbinary(max),convert(nvarchar(max),[mytext]))
FROM @mytable
WHERE [id] = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for but it might be helpful. If you get your `ntext` value to a `nvarchar(max)` value you can use a recursive cte to split the characters and then use [unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) to get the unicode value for each character.

```
declare @txt as nvarchar(max)
set @txt = 'abcåäö€'

;with cte as 
(
  select
    left(@txt, 1) as c,
    stuff(@txt, 1, 1, '') as rest
  union all
  select
    left(rest, 1) as c,
    stuff(rest, 1, 1, '') as rest
  from cte
  where len(rest) > 0
)
select c, unicode(c)
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result

```
---- -----------
a    97
b    98
c    99
å    229
ä    228
ö    246
€    8364
```